# InvokeRepeating generates too much GameObjects

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am using an Invoke Repeating method in Unity that is supposed to generate one cube every two seconds, but once one second has passed many cubes are generated. How can I solve this bug?

```
public class BallsGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cube;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("generateCube", 1.0f, 2.0f);
    }

    private void generateCube()
    {
        Vector3 genPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-111, 823), 728, 378);
        Quaternion startRotation = new Quaternion(Random.Range(-180, 180), Random.Range(-180, 180), Random.Range(-180, 180), 0);
        Instantiate(cube, genPosition, startRotation);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You start a new `InvokeRepeating` **every frame** in `Update`!

So once the delay passed the first time you will get an Object per frame ;)

---

You should rather only do that **once** e.g.

```
private void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("generateCube", 1.0f, 2.0f);
}

private void generateCube()
{
    Vector3 genPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-111, 823), 728, 378);
    Quaternion startRotation = new Quaternion(Random.Range(-180, 180), Random.Range(-180, 180), Random.Range(-180, 180), 0);
    Instantiate(cube, genPosition, startRotation);
}
```